# Seaborn information overlap the axis

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I am facing an issue in which the axis-s are overlapped, how to put the image into a rectangle frame?

[image: The methods are overlapping the axis]

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

stocks_df = pd.read_csv('stocks.csv')
sns.set(font_scale = 1.5)
sns.set_style("white")
sns.catplot(x='Attack Scenarios', y='Ratio (%)',
                 hue="Methods",
                data=stocks_df, kind="box",
            height=6, aspect=1.3);
#plt.savefig("grouped_boxplot_Seaborn_Catplot_Python.png")
plt.show()
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is wrong with the plot you are showing?

Comment: I want to put all things in a box. Not like above

Comment: Still not clear enough. Around the whole figure? around the axes? around the legend? Please refer to https://matplotlib.org/gallery/showcase/anatomy.html or draw the box on your image by hand to explain what you mean

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/rHzQwCk/Screenshot-from-2020-04-02-22-31-38.png here is the result that I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `sns.catplot()` removes the spines on the top and right side. If that's not desired, you may want to use the simpler `sns.boxplot()` since you don't seem to use the FacetGrid anyway. Should yield something line this:

```
tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
ax = sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="time", data=tips)
```

[image]

You can adjust the position of the legend using [`ax.legend(loc=)`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.legend.html?highlight=legend#matplotlib.axes.Axes.legend). If you need to, you can make some room inside the axes for the legend by adjusting the limits of the x-axis

```
tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
ax = sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="time", data=tips)
ax.legend(loc='right')
ax.set_xlim(right=5)
```

[image]

Comment: Anyway, do you know how to make the boxplot looks thinner?